# Count Widgets WordPress

Tags: wordpress, widget

Is there a way to count widgets in widgetized area in WordPress.

I need to add specific class for every 3rd widget.

For example:

```
<div class="widget-item">...</div>
<div class="widget-item">...</div>
<div class="widget-item foo">...</div>

<div class="widget-item">...</div>
<div class="widget-item">...</div>
<div class="widget-item foo">...</div>
```

and so on...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use the `dynamic_sidebar_params` hook for that.

Here's a tutorial for something not so different:
http://wpshock.com/add-first-last-css-class-automatically-to-wordpress-widgets/

In the described solution, you keep a global variable for counting the currents sidebar widgets.
So something like this should enable you to add a class to every 3rd widget:

```
if(($myGlobalCount % 3) == 0){
 //add a custom class
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do this with CSS

```
div.widget-item:nth-child(3n){ 
}
```

Comment: True, but I need support for IE as well.